# Vector Identity For Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, differentiation

I am reading about electrostatics and came across this vector identity when discussing the $D$ field:

$$\frac{\nabla k_{e}}{k_{e}} = \nabla \ln (k_{e}).$$

I have not seen this identity before and was wondering if someone could should me how this is derived

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a basic application of the chain rule, the vector analogue of $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln f(x))=\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{df(x)}{dx}$.

Comment: You beat me for one second. I'd just add that the gradient is putting the three derivatives together in a vector.